# Creating an HTML form from a .doc

Tags: html, forms, .doc

I have a Microsoft .doc document of a form that I am currently having people fill out on paper. I would like the form to be fillable as an html form. What would be the easiest way to make this conversion?

The form is quite long so I'd like to automate the work as much as possible.

Note: I have tried converting the .doc directly to html. While the layout looks nice, the underlining in the .doc is not interpreted as a form field in the html document.

Comment: can you explain the last sentence: 'Note: I have tried converting the .doc directly to html ...'

Comment: Meaning that I tried "view doc as web page". The relative positioning of the form fields looks great.  However, the text is static, it's not a form that can be filled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be very long for it to be easier to find an automatic conversion than just manually create an HTML form. If you recreate it in HTML, you can make smart decisions for the interaction of the form (questions that are skipped depening on the answer to previous questions, etc).

If you just want to convert it one on one, without any effort, [Microsoft Docs](http://docs.com/) or Google Docs is probably easiest.

Answer (score 3):

I think I would use Google docs for this. If you make a spreadsheet you're able to choose that it can be filled via a form you design from a wizard. When the form is filled out, all the data is inputted into the spreadsheet and then exportable to excel or where ever you might need it.

More info here: https://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=87809&&hl=en

Comment: The issue is that I don't want to have to recreate the design of this form, as the form is very long. That's why I'm trying to automate the process.